# unreachable code after return statement, while open social media links from a widget

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver

I have a widget that contains the buttons of social media icons, below is the image:

[image]

and html code

```
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse social-icon" id="socialwidget-nav">
 <ul id="HeaderSocialIcons" class="nav-pills">
     <li class="facebook-icon">
         <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.facebook.com/324421790958939' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
     </li>
     <li class="twitter-icon">
         <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.twitter.com' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
     </li>
     <li class="linkedin-icon">
         <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.linkedin.com' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
 </li>
 <li class="google-icon">
     <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.google.com1' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
     </li>
     <li class="youtube-icon">
     <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.youtube.com' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
     </li>
     <li class="instagram-icon">
         <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.Instagram.com' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
 </li>
 <li class="pinterest-icon">
     <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='https://www.pintrest.com' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
 </li>
 <li class="blog-icon">
     <a id='ImageUrlNavigate' class='socialWidgetIcon' href='/MyBlog.aspx' target = '_blank' style='margin:0px;'></a>
     </li>
 </ul>
```

I want to open all social media links by using this script

```
package TestScripts;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.Keys;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class TestSemiCustom {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:/geckodriver/geckodriver-v0.21.0-win64/geckodriver.exe");
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\Hassan\\Documents\\eclipseworkspace\\WebDriverProject\\lib\\chromedriver.exe");

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.example.com/");
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        String oldTab = driver.getWindowHandle();
        Actions action= new Actions(driver);
        List<WebElement> socialMediaIcons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='ImageUrlNavigate']"));
        System.out.println("Size of list = " + socialMediaIcons.size());
        for (WebElement AllSocial : socialMediaIcons)
        {
            String Name =  AllSocial.getAttribute("href");
            System.out.println(Name);
            AllSocial.click();
        }
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50, TimeUnit.SECONDS);        
                  action.keyDown(Keys.CONTROL).keyDown(Keys.SHIFT).sendKeys(Keys.TAB).build().perform();

    }

}
```

And atlast user will navigate to the parent tab

But i am receiving an error below:

> JavaScript warning: https://static.xx.fbcdn.net/rsrc.php/v3ik7f4/yY/l/en_GB/zomArbZJYcR.js, line 1094: unreachable code after return statement

Note that this social media using on both header and footer with same html code

What I need to do?

Comment: This is a Javascript warning.  If your code isn't working, I would guess it is something else.  In what way isn't it working?

Comment: I think the issue is that, this widget place the on the page multiple times, on header and also on footer with same html code, means its getting me the same xpth and when I apply for loop giving me the size of the webelement list 16, 8 for header social media links and 8 for footer social media link, thats why its going to infinite loop

Comment: Can you show file zomArbZJYcR.js arround line 1094? The error message means there are commands after a return statement. A return statement, means the end of a metho so any command after it, can never be executed.

Comment: What is getting into an infinite loop?  Which code?

Answer (score 0):

You can open all of them using LeftCtrl + LeftClick.

I added an example in C# to demonstrate it

```
Actions actions = new Actions(browser);
actions.KeyDown(Keys.LeftControl);
for (IWebElement socialIcon in allSocialIcons)
{
    actions.Click(socialIcon);
}      
actions.KeyUp(Keys.LeftControl)
    .Build()
    .Perform();
```

It adds all the socialIcons to the action list and only then performs it.